# Flutter changing State of a Widget from another Page

Tags: flutter, dart

my problem in short: i'll try to change the state of a widget from another widget.

in long:

- i have a page.
- this page shows a colored container
- from another page, this colored container should change its color

I would be grateful for any help

```dart
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  
  class Display extends StatefulWidget {
    Display({Key? key, required this.color}) : super(key: key);
  
    Color color;
  
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => DisplayState();
  }
  
  class DisplayState extends State<Display> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        color: widget.color,
      );
    }
  
    changeColor(Color color) {
      setState(() {
        widget.color = color;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can send parametre to another page.

Comment: If you have the page that you want to change it's color as a child of the page that changes the color then you can pass a parameter between them as Joelson suggested , if that's not the case then it's better to use provider

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I get correctly what do you want, but if I'm right you could do this:

- Make a variable of type Color;
- Make a function that change the state of this variable (setState);
- Pass this function as argument to your widget, where you want to change the color.
- Call the function in your other page.

**Your first screen should have a variable to hold the Color value**

`Color containerColor;`

**A function to change its value**

```
void _setContainerColor(Color newColor) {
  setState(() {
    containerColor = newColor;
  });
}
```

**And use the variable in your container**

```
Container(
  color: containerColor, // your variable state
  child: SomeWidget(),
);
```

**Pass your function as argument to your second page**

```
MyOtherWidget(_setContainerColor);
```

**And at your Other Widget, you declare a variable of Function type to receive your function:**

```
const MyOtherWidget(this._setContainerColor) extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function _setContainerColor;

  @override
  _MyOtherWidgetState createState() => _MyOtherWidgetState();
}

class _MyOtherWidgetState extends State<_MyOtherWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      child: Text("Change Color"),
      onPressed: () {
        widget._setContainerColor(Colors.red);
      },
    )
  }
}
```

**Don't forget to use your `containerColor` as value in your Container background color.**

Comment: Thanks, that was my initial idea but i am failing with getting the method done.
I am only able to call setState() in my State class but not my Stateful Widget and so i don't know how to access this method from outside

Comment: @Yuki, you can call inside your widget by calling `widget._setContainerColor`

Comment: can you provide an example with more code? so that i get the lines between the state and the statefulwidget right?
For example: should i put the code for _setContainerColor in the state classe? then how do i call this from another widget?

Comment: I edited my response, it's bad to put large code here.

Comment: ok i see we're talking about different things. imagine i have a wounderful white page. now i am swiping to the right page and want to change the color of the first page to green, or blue, whatever my heart belongs.

Comment: If your widget tree is more complex, I think you probably should use [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

But some states persist even when you change to another screen. If you change the state from your second screen, and come back to first screen, I really think the color will be changed.